# Catch all exceptions and display dynamic error page Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently working on a Rails 4 app and have come to the point where I want to display a custom error page to the user when any exception occurs. Currently it is using the 500.HTML in the public directory.

How can I get the app to render an erb file instead as I want to have some dynamic stuff on the page.

Thanks for you help,
Alex

Comment: I just found this set of instructions: http://makandracards.com/makandra/12807-custom-error-pages-in-rails-3-2 It probably works with Rails 4 as well

Answer (score 6):

ApplicationController have method [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) rescue exceptions raised in controller actions:

in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from YouAwesome::Exception do |exception|
    render_403(exception)
  end

  def render_403(exception)
    logger.warn("Message for log.")
    @error_message = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/errors', layout: false, status: 500 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500 }
    end
  end

end
```

Now you can create views in errors folder `errors.html.erb` and render `@error_message` variable.
That it.

Answer (score 2):

There's an awesome tutorial by Ryan which explains exception handling in rails, have a look at this one http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions

Comment: this tutorial very old, now rails have flexible method for rescue exception.

Comment: There's revised version of the tutorial

Comment: on your link tutorial date `Jul 04, 2007` , put revised version.